# How to spread using dcast?

Tags: r, reshape2, tidyr

I'd like to write the `tidyr::spread` call below in terms of `reshape2::dcast`

```
stocks <- data.frame(
  time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
  X = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Y = rnorm(10, 0, 2),
  Z = rnorm(10, 0, 4)
)
stocksm <- stocks %>% gather(stock, price, -time)

stocksm %>% spread(time, price)
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what to pass to `fun.aggregate`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(stocksm, stock ~ time)
```